# How to pass values from C# to JavaScript using MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

I am working on a progress bar to update the user experience when we request data from the server. I have a Bootstrap progress bar that is updated it from JavaScript. I want pass the progress of the bar by passing the value from C# code. Here is what I have so far:

This is the HTML file:

```
<div class="progress">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfldVariable" runat="server" />
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript File:

```
//Progress Bar
var progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
var progressNumber = "Here will go value from C# file";

setInterval(function () {
progressBar.css('width', progressNumber + '%');
progressBar.attr('aria-valuenow', progressNumber);
}, 100)
```

This is the C# value that I want to pass:

```
   public int progressBarPercentage;
   
   //listPrices.Count is List that updates when we request information from the server
   progressBarPercentage = listPrices.Count;
```

I try to use "<%=progressBarPercentage%>" but is not working, there is any other approach to this. Thank you

Comment: I'm thinking sockets.

Comment: Are you using the ASP.NET MVC framework? Or just the model view controller pattern? Some of the syntax in your question suggests you're using Web Forms.

Comment: @mason I am using ASP.NET MVC framework

Comment: @RobertHarvey can you explain why do you mean sockets?

Comment: Then why are you using Web Forms controls like `asp:HiddenField` and Web Forms syntax like `<%=progressBarPercentage%>`?

Comment: @mason I though will work with .net, what is the best approach to this?

Comment: The usual GET/POST cycle is not real-time, which is why your progress bar percentage does not update.  A socket allows you to make a connection that will update that value in real-time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You mean a web socket? I can imagine someone researching "sockets" and going down a long rabbit hole before even encountering web sockets. Robby - and then eventually they might arrive at SignalR, which is how real time updates are typically pushed from server to client in an ASP.NET application

Comment: You can't just use Web Forms controls in an ASP.NET MVC app. ASP.NET MVC views (.cshtml files) use Razor syntax, not Web Forms controls. Make sure you don't get your frameworks confused.